# Qt Project Dyld Error Setting rpath

Tags: macos, qt, dyld, qtwebengine, rpath

I have a Qt project and I need to include some libraries

I have this in my .pro file:

```
 QT += webengine
```

I can build and run it fine on my Mac but if I try to send the .app to someone else and they run it, there is this error:

```
Dyld Error Message:
 Library not loaded: @rpath/QtWebEngine.framework/Versions/5/QtWebEngine
 Referenced from: /path/myApp.app/Contents/MacOS/myApp
 Reason: image not found
```

I have the QtWebEngine.framework and its corresponding QtWebEngine.framework.dSYM file in my directory:

```
 Users/myUsername/Qt/5.11.0/clang_64/lib
```

I also have the .framework in my directory:

```
 Library/Frameworks
```

In the editor, I looked at Projects > Desktop Qt 5.11.0 clang 64bit2 > Run > Run Environment, and I found that the DYLD_FRAMEWORK_PATH points to where the .framework file is located. Same for DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH.

This is confusing me because it works on my Mac but not on others. It also seems like the paths are all in order. I have tried using other suggestions on this website but they do not seem to work for me or maybe I just did them wrong. Maybe someone could help me?

Update:

If I need to add the .pak resource files to my deployment, how can I do this?

Comment: Could [this](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwebengine-deploying.html) be of any help?

Comment: How did you deply the `.app` I would recommend using [macdeployqt](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/osx-deployment.html#the-mac-deployment-tool)